# How to sort array of structs by given member in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct

I have a struct like that :

```
struct Car {
    int weight;
    int price;
    int speed;
    etc..}
```

I want to write a function to sort array of this kind of structs.

```
void sortCars(struct Car table[], int tableSize, ?structMemberParameter?)
{
    struct Car temp;
    int swapped;
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
    {
        swapped = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < tableSize - 1; j++) {
            if (table[j].?structMemberParameter? > table[j + 1].?structMemberParameter?) {
                temp = table[j + 1];
                table[j + 1] = table[j];
                table[j] = temp;
                swapped = 1;
            }           
        }
        if (swapped == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What should I put as "?structMemberParameter?"?

Comment: `size_t` by `offsetof`

Comment: As you've described the problem, there is no solution.   If you relax constraints you've imposed, there are solutions.   One is to use separate comparators, as described by iharob.  Another is to write a macro instead of a function - with the downside that such a macro is not particularly safe, and incorrect usage will give really confusing error messages from the compiler.     I'd stick with the separate comparators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a comparison function that compares such member from two structs and using `qsort()`. You can see the example in the [`qsort(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) manual.

This is the answer to the title of the question, the answer to your question is you don't need to pass the member but the comparison function just like `qsort()` does.

So the `if` statement becomes

```
if (compare(&table[j], &table[j + 1]) > 0) ...
```

and the function signature

```
typedef int (*cmpfn_type)(const struct Car *const, const struct Car *const);
void sortCars(struct Car table[], int tableSize, cmpfn_type compare);
```

So you can have multiple comparison functions, for example let's say you want to compare by price, the appropriate one would be

```
int compare_by_price(const struct Car *const A, const struct Car *const B)
{
    return (int) (A->price - B->price);
}
```

you should be careful with the type casting though.

The good thing of this approach, is that you can easily rewrite the comparison function to use the `qsort()` library function.

NOTE: Answering to your comment/question in the comments you could also have an enumerator, like

```
enum CarProperties {
    Speed, Price // ... AND SO ON
};
```

and then a sort function like

```
void sort_car_array(struct Car *const array,
        size_t size, enum CarProperties sort_property);
```

where you have a `switch` statement to choose the appropriate callback to pass to a generic sort like say, `generic_car_array_sort()` like the suggested above or even, directly to `qsort()` which would be a better solution.

If your intention is to have an API for the `struct Car` structure you can do it like this and I think it's a very elegant solution. I also recommend making the struct opaque and allowing the caller only to set/get the values via functions.

Comment: I can write comparator for every member, but can I write universal sorting function that will always work, sortCars(struct , Size, speed), sortCars(struct , Size, price) etc..? Without the need for new comparators, all members can be ints, so all comparators will be the same, differs only in member name.

Comment: @PawełDymowski: you can consider a 'universal comparator' function, but you'll probably need to use the offset (via the `offsetof` macro from `<stddef.h>`) and the length and the type of the data because you've probably got some character strings as well as a set of integers (and maybe some floating point numbers, such as the for the fuel consumption or the size of the fuel tank), and handling all those cleanly in a single function is moderately fiddly.

Comment: @PawełDymowski if you want to have all members of the same type accessible with a selector computed at run-time, use an array. `enum CarProperties{Speed, Price, ..., NumProperties}; struct Car { int properties[NumProperties]; };`